# Which of the following sets are regular and which are not? Give justification.

Tags: regular-expressions, finite-automata

Which of the following sets are regular and which are not? Give justification.

a) $\{a^nb^{2m}\mid n\ge 0\text{ and }m\ge 0\}$
b) $\{a^nb^m\mid n\ne m\}$
c) $L((a^*b)^*a^*)$
d) $\{a^nb^nc^n\mid n\ge 0\}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Any help to guide me please :)

Note: I am not looking for the answers, but help to get to them.

- From Kozen textbook

Comment: The asterisks in (a), (b), and (d) appeared to stand for concatenation, so I simply removed them; in (c), however, I wasn’t sure whether the first one or two were concatenation, or whether all three were Kleene stars, so I left it alone. Please let me know what it should be.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I added the picture from the exact text for (c).

Comment: Thanks! They’re Kleene stars, and I’ve entered them as such.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the notation in (c) means *the language of the regular expression inside the parentheses*, the answer for that part should be immediate. For the other three, a useful general principle is that if $x$ and $y$ are two letter in the alphabet of the language, and the language requires a very specific relationship between the number of $x$s and the number of $y$s in a word, then there’s a reasonable possibility that the language is not regular.

For instance, the language $\{a^nb^n:n\ge 0\}$, whose words all contain the same number of $a$s as $b$s, is the classic example of a context-free language that is not regular. There are exceptions when the requirement is enforced locally (i.e., in short segments): the language $\{(ab)^n:n\ge 0\}$ also contains only words with the number of $a$s as $b$s, and it *is* regular, since it’s just $L((ab)^*)$, the language of the regular expression $(ab)^*$.

If you suspect that one of the languages *is* regular, you can try to prove it in at least three ways: $(1)$ show that it’s the language of a regular expression; $(2)$ find a regular grammar that generates it; $(3)$ find a DFA or NFA that accepts/recognizes it. That’s fairly easy for all of the regular languages here.

If you suspect that one is *not* regular, try to prove this by using the [pumping lemma for regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) or the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem); there are examples of the use of both on this site, especially the pumping lemma, that you can find pretty easily by searching. (A Google search on `pumping lemma regular site:math.stackexchange.com` is probably more effective than the site’s own search engine.) The Myhill-Nerode theorem is probably the easier way to deal with one of the languages.

I’ve given the numbers of regular and non-regular languages amongst the four in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Two are regular and two are not.

Comment: Ahh okay I see it now. Though the 0 in the bounds is troubling me a bit. Say for (a) which I now know is regular, what would the regular expression look like? Would it be $aa^*bb(bb)^*$ ?

Comment: @sai98s: Not quite: that doesn't give you the empty word, i.e., the case $m=n=0$. It would be right if the lower bounds on $m$ and $n$ were $1$. You want $a^*(bb)^*$.

Comment: oh okay that makes sense! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @sai98s: You’re welcome!